# Identify rug pieces in this library scene

Tags: part-identification

Can anyone identify the roundish pieces that make up the rug in [this scene](https://www.flickr.com/photos/43699326@N00/31253131311)?

[image: Rug photo]

Answer (score 16):

It's hard to tell for sure, but I believe that it is [Bar Holder with Clip (11090)](http://Bar%20Holder%20with%20Clip%20(11090)).

[image: 11090]

The size and shape look about right to me, and it is widely available in those colors.

Comment: I agree. And from the larger photos linked in the question it is clear this MOC has enough room under the floor for a support structure to keep everything in place.